# Make choice from list of inputs required

Tags: forms

I have a list of inputs as outlined below that are used in a form:

```html
<li data-input-trigger>
  <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q3" data-info="This will help us know what kind of service you need">How happy are you with our service today?</label>
  <br>
  <!--This will help us know what kind of service you need-->
  <div class="fs-radio-group fs-radio-custom clearfix fs-anim-lower">

    <span><input id="q3d" name="q3" type="radio" value="ok"/><label for="q3d" class="radio-ok"></label>Very Unhappy</span>
     
    <span><input id="q3e" name="q3" type="radio" value="mobile"/><label for="q3e" class="radio-mobile">Unhappy</label></span>

    <span><input id="q3c" name="q3" type="radio" value="bad"/><label for="q3c" class="radio-bad"></label>Nutral</span>
     
    <span><input id="q3a" name="q3" type="radio" value="conversion"/><label for="q3a" class="radio-conversion">Happy</label></span>

    <span><input id="q3b" name="q3" type="radio" value="social"/><label for="q3b" class="radio-social"></label>Very Happy</span>
     
    </div>
</li>
```

Does anyone know how I can make a selection form the list mandatory, i.e. required, I know this can be done with standard html form inputs but not when using a list as outlined?

Comment: You will have to calrify what you mean by mandatory - you did not provide any feedback mechanism in the page - is there a button missing? If so, why not use a form (using radio input)?

Comment: Use javascript to submit the form only when the info u r looking for is there.